# Scrollview not scrolling in a uitableview

Tags: nstableview

the scrollview in uitableview is not scrolling and it has another tableview in it.

here is the code that i followed

https://github.com/codedad/SO_ScrollView_with_Tables

Comment: post your code directly by copypasting it inside code tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using scrollview in table view as it already contains scrollview. and then it is conflict which scrollview to scroll.

Better approach is to add horizontal and vertical scrolls so that no conflicts.